# I need to select instead of echo/print

Tags: php, html

I have 3 courses on my site, so when you click sign up you are going to the sign up page where I have one drop down menu and I need to show course which is selected. Now I did everything but I am using echo, and than I have problem because I have 2 same courses. 
You will see in the code:

```
$myCourse = intval($_GET['course_id']);

if ($myCourse) { ?>

        <select id='course' class='form-text'>

<?php
    foreach ( $courses as $course ) {
        if ( $myCourse == $course->id ): 
?>

                    <option selected data-price="<?php print $course->price ?>"><?php print $course->post_name ?></option>

<?php   
        endif; 
?>

                    <option data-price="<?php echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>

<?php 
    } 
?>
        </select>
<?php 
}  else {  
?>
        <pre>

        <select id='select-course' class='signup__form-text'>
            <option selected disabled>-- Select Course --</option>
<?php
    foreach ( $courses as $course ) { 
?>

                <option data-price="<?php  echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>

<?php 
    } 
?>
        </select>
<?php 
}
return ob_get_clean();
```

SO on the spot where is **"print"** I need something to select that choice not to print it out. Because I echo my 3 courses later and now I add existing course. 
So I need select instead of print.
Can someone give me some tip?

Comment: @clearshot66 What is your point? I don't need to echo it i need to select existing one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this code

```
<select id='select-course' class='signup__form-text'>
        <!-- If have id select it in drop down -->

        <?php
        foreach ( $courses as $course ) {

            if ( $myCourse == $course->id ) { ?>

                <option selected data-price="<?php echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>

            <?php } else { ?>

                <option data-price="<?php echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>
 <?php } ?>

          <?php } ?>
         </select>
```

not tested

you can also use this code

```
<select id='select-course' class='signup__form-text'>
    <?php
    foreach ( $courses as $course ) { ?>

            <option <?php if ( $myCourse == $course->id ) { ?> selected <?php } ?> data-price="<?php echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
     </select>
```

also this is work

```
<select id='select-course' class='signup__form-text'>
<?php
foreach ($courses as $course) { ?>

    <option <?php if ($myCourse == $course->id) {
        echo 'selected="selected"';
    } ?> data-price="<?php echo $course->price ?>"><?php echo $course->post_name ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: That is it, works for me! Thanks!

Comment: I give to you as a best answer but I can rate up your answer because I have small rate, someone need to rate my question. I'll give you When I can. Thanks one more time!

Comment: ok i will do up vote

Comment: Amazing man! Your answers are amazing!

Comment: thank you for comment...

Comment: Still need 7 more badges for rating, but when I get it I will not forget this answer you can be sure!

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operators

```
<select>
<?php
  foreach($courses as $course){
    echo ($myCourse == $course->id ? "<option selected value='$course->price'</option>" :  "<option  value='$course->price'</option>"
  }
?>
</select>
```